# For loop not incrementing even after initialization

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a method in java which runs a for loop and within the for loop there are a set of more functions that need to be executed multiple times. Below is the code snippet for reference. My issue is that it is not incrementing with/without initialization in both places

```
    public class dashboardStepDef {
   public int i=2;
    //method to for loop to iterate scenario outline
    public void methodToCall() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i=2; i<=5;i++){
            //add wait
            filterIcon(null);
            enterTextOne(null);
            selectSpecificLogic(null);
            enterTextTwo(null);
            filterButton();
            verifyRow();
            clearFiltersGrid();
            collapseGridRow();
        }
    }
```

---

"public int i;" in the class is being accessed in the code below

```
 public void filterIcon(String columnHeader) throws 
        InterruptedException {
          // determine row
        Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='grid']//table[@role='grid']/thead[@role='rowgroup']/tr[@role='row']/th["+i+"]//span")).click();
            }
```

"i" in the second snippet is the one that is not being incremented

Comment: What is the purpose of the `int i=2;` outside the method?

Comment: What specifically is "not incrementing" and how specifically are you observing this?  Please provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically what observation you are making and what you are expecting (and why).

Comment: i++ is incrementing the local variable of the for loop (declared at the beginning of the for loop), so you will be able to see the incrementation only inside the for loop, and not outside.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code and it works fine. If you are still experiencing an issue, could you please share more context?

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        new Test().methodToCall();
    }

    static class Test {
        int i=2;
//method to for loop to iterate scenario outline
        public void methodToCall() throws InterruptedException {
            for (int i=2; i<=5; i++) {
                //add wait
                // filterIcon(null);
                // enterTextOne(null);
                // selectSpecificLogic(null);
                // enterTextTwo(null);
                // filterButton();
                // verifyRow();
                // clearFiltersGrid();
                // collapseGridRow();
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, World!
23
4
5
```

[EDIT]
If you want to use field `i` you  it is better to use `while` loop

```
    static class Test {
        int i=2;
//method to for loop to iterate scenario outline
        public void methodToCall() throws InterruptedException {
            while (i<=5) {
                //add wait
                // filterIcon(null);
                // enterTextOne(null);
                // selectSpecificLogic(null);
                // enterTextTwo(null);
                // filterButton();
                // verifyRow();
                // clearFiltersGrid();
                // collapseGridRow();
                System.out.println(i);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

But I would suggest pass i parameter into your function:

```
static class Test {
    //method to for loop to iterate scenario outline
            public void methodToCall() throws InterruptedException {
                for (int i=2; i<=5; i++) {
                    //add wait
                    filterIcon(i, null);
                    // enterTextOne(null);
                    // selectSpecificLogic(null);
                    // enterTextTwo(null);
                    // filterButton();
                    // verifyRow();
                    // clearFiltersGrid();
                    // collapseGridRow();
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Apologies, I am new to this community, the method containing for loop calls other methods from within the loop. Snippet of one of the methods is as below, which uses the variable "i" in the xpath which needs to be looped. This is the reason why I had to initialize variable "i" outside the method which contains for loop
 
  public void filterIcon(String columnHeader) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='grid']//table[@role='grid']/thead[@role='rowgroup']/tr[@role='row']/th["+i+"]//span")).click();
        }

Comment: It is in the mentioned xpath that "i" is not being incremented. I declared the variable as public too in the class above but that just highlighted that i has one usage

Comment: @LeenataDeshmukh, I updated answer according to your new comments